# Idiomatic way to handle WebSocket authorization in Akka

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream

Is there an idiomatic way to handle authorization from browser on Akka-based WebSocket endpoint? It looks like Javascript WebSocket API does not allow to send custom authorization headers which means client will probably have to send authorization token via the WebSocket once connection is established. So, what I am essentially looking for is a way to create a flow from sink and source but block it until client sends in a valid authorization message.

Another consideration is, what if authorization token expires at some later point. Supposing client refreshes its token by some external means, is it possible to, again, block the flow until client sends in the refreshed token, or kill the connection if it doesn't happen within some time frame?

This must be a reasonably common use case but for some reason I cannot see obvious way to implement it without writing tons of code. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: How are you creating the WebSocket? If you are using `extractUpgradeToWebSocket` then I think you should be able to authenticate in the usual way before calling it.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that my app has Play backend rather than pure Akka. Therefore WebSocket is created by one of the constructors from play.api.mvc.WebSocket. But I don't think it matters since standard JavaScript API does not allow to pass custom headers to WebSocket connection anyway.